# kotlin Junit test functions syntax

Tags: kotlin

I was going through Javalin github project and found below kotlin test function

```
@Test
fun `ApiBuilder prefixes paths with slash`() = TestUtil.test { app, http ->
    app.routes {
        //code
    }
    assertThat(http.getBody("/level-1/hello"), `is`("Hello from level 1"))
}
```

TestUtil.test is a static method which looks like below

```
public static void test(ThrowingBiConsumer<Javalin, HttpUtil> test) {
    test(Javalin.create(), test);
}
```

I didn't understood what TestUtil.test {} code block is doing here in kotlin tests? is it method overloading or method extension or is it calling static method? I am new to Kotlin so trying to understand this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a static method call, as you guessed.

The code block following it is a lambda, which is passed to the function.  (If the last parameter is a lambda, Kotlin lets you put it after the parentheses — and since in this case there are no other parameters, you can drop the parentheses entirely.  That may look confusing in this case, but it can help to write useful methods that look like language syntax, which is great for e.g. DSLs.)

The other unusual thing about this case is that the method being called is Java.  Java doesn't have function types, but works around it by having ‘functional interfaces’ (interfaces with a single abstract method); lambdas then implement that method.  Kotlin does the same when calling Java, so the code you posted is calling TestUtil.test() and passing it an instance of the ThrowingBiConsumer interface; an instance which implements the relevant method with the code in braces.